# triple \approx and triple \approx with a straight middle line

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm trying to create a symbol `\diffeo` for "diffeomorphic" and `\isomet` for "isometric".

I'd like it to look exactly like \approx $\approx$, but with three lines for the first one; and three lines with the middle being straight for the second one:

[image]
[image]

where approx is the symbol

[image].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first of the following macros is in the [*Comprehensive List of LaTeX Symbols*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (`texdoc symbols`, with TeX Live), where it is called `\threesim`; the second one has been built similarly.

```
\newcommand*{\diffeo}{% 
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip
  \hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.35ex\hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.35ex\hbox{$\sim$}}}}

\newcommand*{\isomet}{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip
  \hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.85ex\hbox{$-$}\vskip-.55ex\hbox{$\sim$}}}}
```

Comment: I've searched *Latex comprehensive symbol list* before, but never found those two symbols. Don't know why they didn't add them as a built-in control and add a **picture** of it. I also checked Detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but never got any suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's on page 104, but I admit that I know where to look even without remembering the command's name. ;-) I built the second one just now.

Comment: 10 years later it's on page 261 :) is it correct that this symbol is not part of LaTeX itself or any package, so the definition needs to be copied in order to use the symbol? Maybe a package can be found that is willing to "host" it?

Comment: @Marijn The code is free for use by anybody.